# Excel 2010 search for text in IF function - separate cell data

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:**  Excel 2010

**Require:**  A way to extract the First Name, Surname, email to individual cells.

**Data:**     My data has a table with original 'dirty data', it's raw and a mess.  I tidy it up using a simple `=IF(A7="Order",1,"")`, then rest of the cells follow:  `=IF($C7=1,B13,"")`

example:

```
  (A) | Orig2              | Header? (C)          | NameAll (K)       | Price          |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Order | Ms Admin (e@m.com) | =IF(A7="Order",1,"") | =IF($C7=1,B13,"") | =IF($C7=1,B5,"")
Order | Mr Joe (e@m.com)   | =IF(A8="Order",1,"") | =IF($C8=1,B14,"") | =IF($C8=1,B6,"")
Order | Ms Fred (e@m.com)  | =IF(A9="Order",1,"") | =IF($C9=1,B15,"") | =IF($C9=1,B7,"")
```

results in:

```
(A)   | Orig2              | Header? (C) | NameAll (K)        | Price  |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Order | Ms Admin (e@m.com) | 1           | Ms Admin (e@m.com) | 13.99
Order | Mr Joe (e@m.com)   | 1           | Mr Joe (e@m.com)   | 15.99
Order | Ms Fred (e@m.com)  | 1           | Ms Fred (e@m.com)  | 17.99
```

**Working**  After I have copied the cell values over, then 'copy/value' on my sheet, I can then use in `(U7)` the following (which extracts the email from between ())
`=IFERROR(MID(K7,(SEARCH("(",K7)+1),((SEARCH(")",K7)-(SEARCH("(",K7)+1)))),"")`

What I want to do is take it from the beginning of the data moving, so I can miss the step completely of copying the old, to new, then data extraction

**Tried:** *failed*
`=IFERROR($C7=1,B13(MID(B13,(SEARCH("(",B13)+1),((SEARCH(")",B13)-(SEARCH("(",B13)+1))))))`

I also come unstuck with a name such as:   W. H. Minder (m@e.net)  when trying to separate the First, Middle, Last (email)

Is it just easier that I run through a number of steps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @pnuts I use Text to Columns for my date conversion, I can see it working with this.  So, continue how I was doing, the 'basic version', then after my final 'copy/values', then split the cells, go back and delete column K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing names is not simple, because of all the variations.  One issue with your data as you've shown it would be testing to see if the First Name was really a title like Mr Ms etc.

My preference would be to do this using VBA and regular expressions, but here are some formulas you can play with:

```
Email:  =MID(TRIM(A1),FIND("(",TRIM(A1))+1,FIND(")",TRIM(A1))-FIND("(",TRIM(A1))-1)
First Name:   =LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))-1)
Middle Name:  =IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))<>3,"",LEFT(MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1,99),FIND(" ",MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1,99))-1))
Last Name:    =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

The First Name will be the First "Word", so you could test to see if it Mr or Mrs or something you don't want to return.

The Middle Name will be returned if and only if there are three names, but that could be rewritten to return all except the First and Last Names

Comment: Thank you. I have no Mr, Mrs, Ms in my data, I shoud've represented it as Joe, Jen, Jac etc. This looks great, I will try it on my data.  But this still only works after the data clean? Not during? I can't write in the original data parsing? `=IF($C7=1,B13,"")` (It's ok if not, but I'd prefer to skip this step if possible).  I always have the cell filled with name (1,2 or 3 parts & an email in () that doesn't change)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "data clean".  In your before and after examples, the data in Orig2 and NameAll appears to be the same.  The formula should work on data in that format -- FN [MN] LN (email)  So I cannot tell what you are trying to do with the Name (email) data.  The formulas will remove extraneous spaces, as you can see by the use of TRIM.  Please provide examples of what you are considering to be "dirty" data.  Perhaps it is as simple as wrapping the formulas into a  construct such as  =if(a1="order",one_of_the_formulas,"")

Comment: This is my sheet: http://imgur.com/hLBh6na It is sales history I have to copy & paste, I clean & order it, the data is always 9 rows & 2 columns per order. Title (A), Value (B). I move each part of the data to 1 order = 1 row by using the anchor: (C7)->`=IF(A7="Order",1,"")` then the data (rows 7+, Col A-Z) `=IF($C7=1,B13,"")`. (P, Q, R) I want the name broken down when I autofill the rest of the information from (C7) down. I currently have to move the name, then break it down, i'd like to try and break it as I move it.  I hope that explains it better :)  Thank you.

Comment: It took me a bit but I relooked at what you wrote & my code and now I have it :) Works perfectly.  I had problems with the Middle name, I didn't know I could have 2 IF in the 1 formula. I do now :)  `=IF($C8=1,(IF(LEN(TRIM(K107))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K107," ",""))<>3,"",LEFT(MID(TRIM(K107),FIND(" ",TRIM(K107))+1,99),FIND(" ",MID(TRIM(K107),FIND(" ",TRIM(K107))+1,99))-1))))`  Gives me "H" as needed, about to run it over my entire sheet now. brilliant!  Thank you.  If you have any advice on my sheet I posted I'd be eager to read. :D

Comment: I'm glad you've got the formulas working.  And yes, you can have multiple IF's in a single formula.  There is a limitation of formula length and nesting, but you shouldn't run into those with what you are trying to do.  With regard to your sheet, you posted an image, so it's not possible for me to work with it without doing a lot of work.  But my initial impression is that it would be much easier for you to use a VBA Macro to extract the required information into a report of some kind.  You'll need to learn about VBA and using macros, but in the long run, it may be time well spent.

Comment: I have taken your advice and decided to make this in VBA, though I cant get it to work. I've posted a new query, if you wouldn't mind taking a look please.  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/q/28467995/2337102

Comment: @MrsAdmin The first thing you need to do is to devise clear and unambiguous rules you wish the VBA algorithm to use in order to separate the names.